# Программное создание checkbox

Tags: android-sdk, android, android-studio

почему все checkbox создаются в одном и том же месте? как сделать что бы они создавались один за другим

Код:

```
 int tmpCountPack = (int)Math.floor(Calc.Lkab()/getResources().getIntArray(R.array.length_set_of_cable)[1] + 1);
            checkBoxes[0].setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.label_set_of_cable)[1] +
                    "\nКол-во комплектов: " + Integer.toString(tmpCountPack) +
                    "\nСумма: " + Integer.toString(getResources().getIntArray(R.array.price_set_of_cable)[1] * tmpCountPack) + "руб\n");
            checkBoxes[0].setChecked(true);
            checkBoxes[0].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            relativeLayoutCalcLayout.addView(checkBoxes[0]);

            checkBoxes[1].setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.label_additional_elements)[0] +
                    "\nКол-во: " + Integer.toString(tmpCountPack) +
                    "\nСумма: " + Integer.toString(getResources().getIntArray(R.array.price_addirional_elements)[0] * tmpCountPack));
            checkBoxes[1].setChecked(true);
            layoutParams.topMargin += checkBoxes[0].getHeight() + 10;
            checkBoxes[1].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            relativeLayoutCalcLayout.addView(checkBoxes[1]);

            checkBoxes[2].setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.label_additional_elements)[1] +
                    "\nКол-во: " + Integer.toString(tmpCountPack) +
                    "\nСумма: " + Integer.toString(getResources().getIntArray(R.array.price_addirional_elements)[1] * tmpCountPack));
            checkBoxes[2].setChecked(true);
            layoutParams.topMargin += checkBoxes[1].getHeight() + 10;
            checkBoxes[2].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            relativeLayoutCalcLayout.addView(checkBoxes[2]);

            checkBoxes[3].setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.label_additional_elements)[2] +
                    "\nКол-во: " + Integer.toString(tmpCountPack) +
                    "\nСумма: " + Integer.toString(getResources().getIntArray(R.array.price_addirional_elements)[2] * tmpCountPack));
            checkBoxes[3].setChecked(true);
            layoutParams.topMargin += checkBoxes[2].getHeight() + 10;
            checkBoxes[3].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            relativeLayoutCalcLayout.addView(checkBoxes[3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что у Вас один и тот же объект LayoutParams для всех чекбоксов.

Перепешите так, чтобы был отдельный объект для каждого чекбокса.